# How can i select or copy a text from a canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

i have created a canvas and wrote a text over it and i want to know how i should make the text copyable 
i hope that someone has the solution 
thank you

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.height = '2000';
canvas.width = '2000';
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.font = "bolder 14px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Text  ", canvas.width /2,canvas.height/2);
```

Comment: A canvas is a field of pixels. Once the text is drawn on the canvas, it's not text anymore; it's just dots.

Comment: and can i not even select it anymore?

Comment: No. It's like a piece of paper. Whatever is on the canvas is just a drawing. An image if you will. At best you could use OCR software to read out the text. But that still wouldn't make it selectable

Comment: I suppose you could make a parent element and make the canvas a child of it. Then add another child element and absolute position it on top. That way it'll look like it's part of the canvas, though obviously it isn't. But it'll be selectable just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. It's like you're a painter and you're painting on your canvas. Differently from svg, if you paint something you won't be able to distinguish it from other painted elements.

Otherwise, you can add a timer or a for cycle and make it update every ms.

Comment: I'm sorry!! My bad, I mispelled it. I meant SVG.

Comment: i couldn't do it with Canvas because canvas doesnt remember the elements they were painted on it , it's very complicated . Because of this i used SVG its so much easier. Thank you for the help

Comment: I'm really glad I helped. I am still learning too and yours was my first accepted answer to a question. I hope you're having as much fun as I am while learning to use svg :)

Comment: i have another question about SVG if you can help me please:

Comment: i have been created this SVG and set width and height in percent 100%
like that :
                    var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
        
       svg.setAttribute('id', 'idsvg');
       svg.setAttribute('width', '100%');
       svg.setAttribute('height', '100%');

but later i want to creat a rect with position 100% - 20px but this didnt work because 100% is not a number .
any idea or help?

Comment: Right now I can't help you, but if you post this as another question maybe another user will help you before me

Comment: plus, seeing your code as enlighted or with a snippet is far better than seing a string :)